# Invalidate disabled query in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I try to fetch data into a form using react-query.

It is disabled by default, because this form also handles empty forms (when no default values are loaded from server, ie.: it is a CREATE option).

It works correctly, but not in the best way.
The cache will be there next time, so if I load the page again, the old data will be visible until the `refetch()` completes.

Is it somehow possible to remove from the cache when leaving the page? (It should always load as it is doing for the first time, when it does not have any cached data for this queryKey).

I have tried using `queryClient.removeQueries()`, but is seems to be not working, I assume it is because the query is in `disabled` state.

```
    const {data, isError, isSuccess, isFetching, isIdle, refetch} = useQuery(queryKey, getProject(id), {
        enabled: false,
        retry: 2,
    });
```

Comment: Where is your code

Comment: where did you used queryClient.removeQueries() on mutate call back or usemutation call back ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the right approach is to set `cacheTime` to 0.

Setting `cacheTime` to 0 will remove the query completely from the cache if React re-renders the page.

```
    const {data, isError, isSuccess, isFetching, isIdle, refetch} = useQuery(queryKey, getProject(id), {
        enabled: false,
        retry: 2,
        cacheTime: 0
    });
```

Comment: if you use usemutation invalide query should work else optimistic update can be a good option though else refetch can be used rather than using cacheTIme or staleTIme

Comment: How can I use useMutation for fetching?

Comment: I mean if you want to update your data after form submission use react mutation else you can use stale time